# Ubuntu Server failed to fetch during update

Tags: apt, server, updates, 19.10

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu server 19.10 it is installed on an Asus F50sv laptop. The screen on the laptop glitches and the bottom half is garbled I can't read anything on it. But I chose to install SSH and I can SSH to the server.

When I SSH in and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following:

```
dave@unms:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for dave:
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan-backports/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan-security/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I can ping 91.189.88.162 from the SSH session. On a PC on the same network I copy and pasted the URL's and it takes me to the package lists.

I am not using a proxy server and DNS is working fine on the server.

Comment: so I did some more troubleshooting:  if I do a sudo wget archive.ubuntu.com I grab the index. If I do sudo wget archive.ubuntu.com/dists/eoan/InRelease it sits at HTTP request sent, awaiting response...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Gryu,  I believe there was some other issues with the laptop I was trying to install on and have decided to use a different one. if I have some extra time I will try it on the old one though.   I did also try going to the ca.archive which also didn't work.  <br> On the newer laptop the fresh install worked as it should.   sudo apt-get upgrade worked without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the next records in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main restricted
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan universe
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan multiverse
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates universe
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates multiverse
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates main restricted
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
```

I do not have InRelease in my config.

But you could check [documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/sources.list.5.html) about this option:

> InRelease-Path (inrelease-path) determines the path to the InRelease
>   file, relative to the normal position of an InRelease file. By
>   default, this option is unset and APT will try to fetch an InRelease
>   or, if that fails, a Release file and its associated Release.gpg file.
>   By setting this option, the specified path will be tried instead of
>   the InRelease file, and the fallback to Release files will be
>   disabled.